# where to place slf4j-nop.jar to run ktor

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, ktor

i,
I followed the instructions "creating a client application"
reading https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html
However at the last step I got the following response:

""
E:\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe "...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
200 OK

Process finished with exit code 0
""

I looked up the named http: page but as I'm new to kotlin I did
not know where to place "slf4j-nop.jar"

Can anyone give a hint.

Joerg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem add the following line to the `dependencies` block in the `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.7")
```

SLF4J requires a logger implementation and uses a no-operation logger implementation by default if none is found on the classpath.